# Can't init cluster for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.1

Now I'am trying to install Postgresql.
I have already:

1. Install postgresql.
2. Create user for database.
3. Create directory for cluster.

And now I can't init cluster here is log of the error.

---

```
postgres@Computer:~$ initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/data --nodename foo

The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locales
  COLLATE:  en_US.UTF-8
  CTYPE:    en_US.UTF-8
  MESSAGES: en_US.UTF-8
  MONETARY: ru_RU.UTF-8
  NUMERIC:  ru_RU.UTF-8
  TIME:     ru_RU.UTF-8
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to UTF8.
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 24MB
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
```

**Error:**

```
 initializing pg_authid ... FATAL:  wrong number of index expressions
    STATEMENT:  REVOKE ALL on pg_authid FROM public;

    child process exited with exit code 1
    initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to overcome this problem? What is the version of GCC you are using?